# Are the ec2 T family instances objectively "worse" than the other ones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wonder why the documentation seems to allude that the T instances should not be used in production. I am most concerned about advertised CPU performance and network availability.

Regardless of the cost and the credits thing, is there any reason to believe that the CPU performance of the T family ec2 instances is worse than other instance types with the same amount of cores and frequency?

Does the T instance have "access" to it's full non-baseline CPU performance as fast as other types? Or is there some kind of delay?

Can the performance of my instance be impacted by other customers putting more load on their instances?

Are latency spikes more likely to happen than with other types of instances?

Comment: I think there is supposed to be a whole family below them. In terms of the title question. I can't answer the others.

Comment: In my experience running load tests against t class instances, there has been no delay/lag when going over the CPU baseline, up until the credits are spent up and it gets throttled.

Comment: Also, keep in mind CPU performance is not the only metric.  For instance, [network performance is burstable as well](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/general-purpose-instances.html#general-purpose-network-performance), and the baseline network performance is lower on the burstable instances compared to other instances types.

Comment: The T family is burstable, so by definition it won't have a consistent performance at high loads. Would you want this in production?